# Cannot run the osmar navigation demo in R. Probably because the demo expects igraph0, which is deprecated

Tags: r, openstreetmap, igraph, osmar

I am trying to run the osmar navigation demo, in R. This demo will use osmar and igraph plot a traffic route around Munich city centre, based on openstreetmap data.

I am using R version 3.1.1 on Lubuntu

The demo, and the osmar library are detailed here http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-1/eugster-schlesinger.pdf

To run the demo I type,

```
library("osmar")
library("igraph")     # The demo tries to call igraph0, but this is 
                      # no-longer available in my version of R, so I
                      # have changed it to "igraph"
demo("navigator")
```

The demo runs perfectly until it reaches the igraph section.

```
gr_muc<-as_igraph(hways_muc)      # make a graph of the highways from openstreetmap
summary(gr_muc)
```

This should return

```
Vertices: 2381
Edges: 2888
Directed: TRUE
No graph attributes.
Vertex attributes: name.
Edge attributes: weight, name.
```

But for me it returns

```
IGRAPH DNW-2385 2894 --
attr: name (v/c), weight (e/n), name (e/n)
```

I know that `gr_muc` is a graph because the commands `E(gr_muc)` and `V(gr_muc)` return lists of edges and vertices.

Then the demo runs

```
route <- get.shortest.paths(gr_muc,from = as.character(hway_start_node),to = as.character(hway_end_node))[[1]]
```

and returns the error

```
At structural_properties.c:4482 :Couldn't reach some vertices
```

Which means that it couldn't link the start and end vertices. Then the script fails.

What do I change to make the demo script run, and why is it not working?

Comment: Since this downloads an OSM data file, its possible the data has changed and the line network isn't connected. I don't see igraph0 anywhere now - where does the demo try to call igraph0?

Comment: Yes, there's definitely a break in the graph. is.connected(gr_muc) is FALSE. I'm sure with some more igraph-fu you could colour the disconnected segments to show....

Comment: @Spacedman, I agree, but the start and end points are both on the map, and they are joined by highways, so there shouldn't be a break in the graph.

Comment: Sorry, the description of the demo in the linked pdf calls igraph0, but I just tried installing igraph0, and analysing the gr_muc with igraph0, and I get exactly the same behaviour.

Comment: I guess this is a bug in igraph. It returns an error even if `to` is reachable from `from`, but some other vertices are not. A workaround would be to extract the component that contains `from` and `to`.

Comment: @ Gabor Csardi, how would I do that?

Comment: @user1348793 Well, it turns out that your problem was solved. That said, the bug might still exist....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some one-way streets that prevent the start and end node being connected. Here's some scrappy code that plots the nodes reachable from the `hway_start` node:

```
plot(hways_muc)

hway_start # osmar object
plot_nodes(hway_start, add = TRUE, col = "red", pch = 19, cex = 2)

# get reachable nodes, return graph Vertex indexes
n1 = neighborhood(gr_muc,200,V(gr_muc)[as.character(hway_start_node)], mode="out")

# get graph subset
allpts = V(gr_muc)[n1[[1]]]

# use names to subset OSM nodes:
nds = subset(muc, node(allpts$name))
plot_nodes(nds, add=TRUE,col="green",pch=19,cex=1)
```

[image: accessible nodes]

Note that you can't get to the top right which is where the end node is in the demo.

You can work round this if you don't mind driving the wrong way up one-way streets by making the graph undirected:

```
gru_muc=as.undirected(gr_muc)
route <- get.shortest.paths(gru_muc,
                             from = as.character(hway_start_node),
                             to = as.character(hway_end_node))[[1]]
```

and now you have a route:

```
> route
[[1]]
  [2] 1444  491 2055  334  331  481  478  479  [etc]
```

BUT the return from `get_shortest_paths` is a list of lists, so you need to get the first component of `route` to continue the demo code:

```
route=route[[1]]
route_nodes <- as.numeric(V(gr_muc)[route]$name)
```

and then plot:

[image: route complete]

So I think firstly, the start and end node are not connected along directed ways, and secondly there's a bug in the demo code so that doesn't get the correct element of the return from `get_shortest_paths`. Its nothing to do with `igraph0`.

Comment: Going the "correct" way down a one-way street is for chumps anyways.

Comment: Perfect! I like to imagine that there are parts of Munich that can only be reached by driving the wrong way down an einbahnstraße.

Comment: or remove the unreachable (oneway) subnetworks like we do in graphhopper before executing queries